# How to solve Iorg.apache.spark.SparkException in sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, hive, log4j, spark-streaming

I'm beginner for **sparklyr**. When I try to use `copy_to()` function I had an error, how can I fix it?

*My code*:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(babynames)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.0.1")
babynames_tbl <- copy_to(sc, babynames, "babynames")
```

*Error*:

> Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage
>   failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost
>   task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:873)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:853)    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:407)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:430)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:422)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike

Comment: Simple question, but what version of Java are you on? Also, did you use the bleeding edge version of sparklyr (devtools)?